# print result from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following query to get results, I am stuck at printing the result in format that I pass it to array and post it to twitter any tips

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT('#', hashtag) AS hashtag, sum(count) as total 
          FROM `trending_topics` WHERE lang=1 and  hashtag != '' and 
          date >= date_sub(left(now(), 10), interval 2 day) group by hashtag 
          order by total desc LIMIT 0, 3";   

$message = mysql_fetch_row($query); 

$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "Trending topics $message"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row` will return the data in the array format. sot get the data you should use the below code:

```
$tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "Trending topics".implode($message)));
```